# Create dimension that filters by range

Tags: iccube

How can I configure a dimension in icCube to filters values based on the range bucket they belong to? For example, if I have many timestamps, how can I bucket the timestamps by hour, or time interval? Or if I have values between 1-20, how can I bucket them into ranges 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20?

Is 'Is Indexing by Range' relevant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the way to go using a Dimension with 'Indexing By Rage'activated (see [doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_ranged.php)).

The idea is to let icCube solve the key using an algo that will walk from the root to the leafs using a binarySearch. Note all levels have to be ordered by the same key type (e.g. numeric).

```
Hot                   [20,
        Unbearable hot    [35,
        Very Hot          [30,35)
        Mildly Hot        [25,30)
        Nice              [20,25)
Cold
        Nicely cold       [15,20)
        Cold              [5,15)
        Freezing              5)
```

Here 22.5  would be 'Nice'.